# Idiomatic for “I suppose”, “I imagine”, “I guess”

Tags: word-choice, idiomaticity

I'm having trouble finding a good idiomatic German phrase for "I suppose that...", "I imagine that...", "I guess that..." as the typical start of a statement that is intended to soften it somehow. If you consult a dictionary you get *sich<sup>Dat</sup> vorstellen* and *annehmen* for "imagine" and "suppose", but I've only ever used *sich<sup>Dat</sup> vorstellen* in its more literal sense of "conjuring up an image in my mind", and *annehmen* sounds more like "assuming a fact as true" than "supposing something might be true".

For example:

> "These have been difficult days, but I imagine they'll be just vague memories in a couple of months."
>
> "She's unprepared but determined. I suppose she'll do fine if she trusts her instincts."
>
> "They tell me he's very angry, so I guess he won't be coming to visit anytime soon."

Is it OK to employ either one of these verbs for my meaning, or is it just not done in German? If the latter, is there any way to translate that idea more idiomatically?

Comment: Your question would get better answers if it had a concrete example.

Comment: I've added some examples to show what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Adding to Christian's answer, I colloquially use: "*Ich wette, (dass) X*" or "*X, nehme ich an.*" in the sense of "*I bet*" or "*I take it*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Es waren schwere Tage, aber in ein paar Monaten sind es sicher nur noch vage Erinnerungen.
>
> Sie ist nicht bereit, aber enschlossen. Wenn sie ihrem Instinkt traut, wird sie wohl Erfolg haben.
>
> Er soll sehr erzürnt sein, also wird er wohl nicht so bald zu Besuch kommen.

In other words, *don't assume that verbs are most idiomatically translated to verbs*. Particularly in E->D transfer, a verb with adverbial sense often corresponds to a German modal particle. Mastering these modal particles is somewhat tricky, but it increases the quality of translation considerably.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Muss ich neidvoll anerkennen.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions in German for "I suppose that..."

> Ich glaube, der Eiffelturm steht in Paris.
>
> Ich denke, London liegt an einem großen Fluß.
>
> Ich vermute, die Erde dreht sich links herum.
>
> Ich meine, die Corrioliskraft schubbst Flüsse ein bisschen nach Norden.
>
> Ich würde mal sagen, Europa ist kein richtiger Kontinent.
>
> Man sollte meinen, Amerika ist weit genug weg.
>
> Es liegt nahe zu vermuten, dass der schiefe Turm von Pisa nicht immer schief war.
>
> Man könnte annehmen, dass der Mond irgendwann auf die Erde plumpst.
>
> Mir dünkt, Venedig hat schon bessere Tage gesehen. [Very old-fashioned]
>
> Mich deucht, mich küsst ein Schwan. [Also old fashioned; use this only ironically]

A bit different than what you intended are probably the following expressions of opinion - as their focus is not so much "unsecure belief", rather something like "that's my opinion, and I admit that others can have other opinions".

> Nach meinem Dafürhalten ist der Norden Vietnams schöner als der Süden. [Sounds a bit stiff, bureaucratic.]
>
> Nach meiner Einschätzung werden die Jahre immmer trockener.
>
> Meiner Meinung nach ist Bologna ein weithin unterschätztes Reiseziel.
>
> Ich würde sagen, Rom ist einer Reise wert.
>
> Ich tät mal sagen, Rom ist einfach überlaufen. [Colloquially]

---

As there were concrete examples added later:

> "These have been difficult days, but I imagine they'll be just vague memories in a couple of months."
>
> "She's unprepared but determined. I suppose she'll do fine if she trusts her instincts."
>
> "They tell me he's very angry, so I guess he won't be coming to visit anytime soon."

You can use here practically all of the above examples: ich vermute, ich glaube, ich denke, ich würde sagen, ich meine, man sollte meinen, etc. The difference is merely one of register of speech.